# Words with regional variations in gender

Tags: gender, regional

Whilst 'die Butter' is almost universal in German, 'der Butter' is a regional variant, especially in Swabia (apparently). Similarly, one can say die SMS (North/Central) or das SMS (Southern).

Is anyone aware of, or has anyone compiled a list of words which whist otherwise identical, have regional variations in gender.

Comment: Sorry for closing this, since the "duplicate" is a German question, but you should recognize its content.

Comment: No need to apologise. Thanks to yourself and all the individuals involved in finding me an answer!